# JavaScript is not catching the correct list item from JQuery-AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions main function which JQuery , and the other one in Javascript.

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#ProvisionLink').click(function () {
    var queryTargetList = [ "Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"]
    var data =  ["Data1","Data2","Data3","Data4" ]
    event.preventDefault();
    var i;

    for(i = 0; i < queryTargetList.length; ++i) {
          var dataItem = data[i];
          var QueryItems = queryTargetList[i];
          console.log("Before Launching the Javascript : " +QueryItems)
          $.ajax({
            url: '/operation',
            data: {DataType: dataItem,},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response){ getInventory(response,QueryItems) },
            error: function (error) {console.log(error);}
            });
    }

  });
});
```

Java script :

```
   function getInventory(data,queryTarget){
  console.log("In Get Inventory Function in javascript ... " +queryTarget)
  var queryTarget = "#"+queryTarget

  // get the query id
  const SelectBoxQuery = document.querySelector(queryTarget)
  console.log(SelectBoxQuery)
  // resetting the values to enter all the new one.
  SelectBoxQuery.options.length = 0; // reset the values

  // making a loop to reach each element item in the list
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    // add new element which is option to the targeted ID
    var SelectBoxQuery_Addition = document.createElement('option');

    // adding a text to that option
    SelectBoxQuery_Addition.text = data[i];

    // apply the adding .
    SelectBoxQuery.add(SelectBoxQuery_Addition)

  }}
```

The problem is, after i get response from python FLASK to Jquery function. in success part it should launch the javascript function with the same i of the queryTargetList.

for example if i pass data[1], i expect to have  queryTargetList[1] also.

but in javascript console.log function. that does not happen. it printing the last item of the queryTargetList list.

Print:

```
Before Launching the Javascript : Item1
JQueryTests.js:11 Before Launching the Javascript : Item2
JQueryTests.js:11 Before Launching the Javascript : Item3
JQueryTests.js:11 Before Launching the Javascript : Item4
operationJavaScript.js:115 In Get Inventory Function in javascript ... Item4
In Get Inventory Function in javascript ... Item4
In Get Inventory Function in javascript ... Item4
In Get Inventory Function in javascript ... Item4
```

I do not know what am doing wrong :(

Comment: Just change `var QueryItems` to `let QueryItems`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the ajax call is an async operation, the loop variable `i` would have changed by the time the success method gets called. There is no guarantee that the `i` would have reached the end.
You would need to wrap the variables, in a closure so that it success methods gets the correct item.
Sample code not tested.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#ProvisionLink').click(function () {
var queryTargetList = [ "Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"]
var data =  ["Data1","Data2","Data3","Data4" ]
event.preventDefault();
var i;

for(i = 0; i < queryTargetList.length; ++i) {
      var dataItem = data[i];
      var QueryItems = queryTargetList[i];
      console.log("Before Launching the Javascript : " +QueryItems)
      (data,queryItem)=>{
         $.ajax({
           url: '/operation',
           data: {DataType: data,},
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (response){ getInventory(response,queryItem) },
           error: function (error) {console.log(error);}
        });
      })(dataItem,QueryItems);
}

});
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, i have tested the solution which provided by Mr.MD. RAKIB HASAN, and it worked.

Comment: @Leivir, if you set the async to false, you will end up queuing up requests.

Comment: is that means, i cant call another request, till the first one is completed ?

Comment: yes, it will happen one after the other.

Answer (score 2):

set the `async` option to `false`:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/operation',
            data: {DataType: dataItem,},
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response){ getInventory(response,QueryItems) },
            error: function (error) {console.log(error);}
            });
```

Another way: send `queryTargetList[i]` value to server and response get from server..

Comment: @Leivir your browser will freeze if you use `async: false` if the ajax takes a few seconds

Answer (score 2):

You must consider the issue of synchronization and non-synchronization, because you did not set the async attribute, so the default will be true. The easiest way is to set the async attribute to false

Like my example below, for detailed usage, you can refer to [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```js
  $.ajax({
    url: '/operation',
    data: {DataType: dataItem,},
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function (response){ getInventory(response,QueryItems) },
    error: function (error) {console.log(error);}
  });
```